# How do I publish CSV file to Tableau Server?

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am trying to use Python to publish a datasource to my Tableau Online Server using the Tableau REST API.

My publishing code will look something like this:

```py
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/xml',
    'X-Tableau-Auth': accessToken
}

fileToUpload = open("my file", "r")

**THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO BUILD MY BODY**

req = requests.post(url, data = body, headers = headers)

res = json.loads(req.text)

print(json.dumps(res, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

The docs [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_data_sources.htm#publish_data_source) say to to post with the following as the request body

```xml
--boundary-string
Content-Disposition: name="request_payload"
Content-Type: text/xml
<tsRequest>
    <datasource name="datasource-name"
    useRemoteQueryAgent="use-remote-query-agent-flag"
    description="datasource-description">
        <connectionCredentials name="connection-username"
         password="connection-password"
            embed="embed-flag" />
        <project id="project-id" />
  </datasource>
</tsRequest>
--boundary-string
Content-Disposition: name="tableau_datasource"; filename="datasource-file-name"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
content-of-datasource-file
--boundary-string--
```

All the other Tableau REST API calls seem to accept json, but uploading with json body returns a 406 - json not accepted error.

How do I build my XML body with a csv file for the datasource? What I am first confused about is the `--boundary-string` part. What exactly is this and how should I load in a csv file to publish through this?

My other question. In the docs, there is also a note `datasource-file-type  hyper, tds, tdsx, or tde`. I know that I can manually upload a CSV file though. My ultimate goal is (using the Tableau REST API) to upload a datasource, take a predefined and empty workbook template, create a new workbook from that, and connect my datasource to the new workbook so I can generate a report. Is there a simpler way to do all of this? And will I be able to do this with a csv? I know that I can translate a csv to hyper file but I don't need any of the hyper file capabilities for my reports.

**Update**

Tableau Online allows you to upload csv files manually but not using the rest api. Only tds, tdsx, tde, hyper files can be published as datasources. What would be the best way to convert a csv file to one of these file formats? The Hyper API offers some methods [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/hyper_api/en-us/docs/hyper_api_insert_csv.html) but that seems like a lot of extra stuff I don't need.

Comment: You've got multiple questions wrapped into this one so it's hard to provide a single answer. I have had good experience using Tableau's Server Client (TSC) library in python for my workbook and data source interactions. https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/. It beats writing your own request headers and bodies and keeps up with changes in Tableau functionality.

Comment: yeah I know, sorry about that, I'm just getting a little lost in the weeds with this one. Mainly, I wanted to know how the XML works for these requests. And secondly, a more generic one, if anyone has had any success uploading datasources and how. I really just need to find the best solution to take some csv data and create a workbook report from it. I'll take a look in the TSC library again. I had started there at some point but it didn't give me full access to everything in the rest api so I dropped it early on

Comment: Why not just use Tableau Prep Builder to create a flow that takes your CSV file as input and publishes a Hyper extract to your server as output?

Comment: @AlexBlakemore is that something that I could automate? It looks to me like something that would be attached to Tableau desktop, which I'm not using. The eventual goal is to automatically take some csv file and create a report. To do that I need a pipeline that can create a new data source and workbook then connect the two.

Comment: Yes, of course the goal is always to automate data pipelines, even if you make early versions with a man in the loop -- so even if you use the client application Tableau Prep Builder do define your flow initially, that doesn't necessarily mean you use that tool during eventual ongoing operations. So my recommendation is to first try using Tableau Prep Builder to make and publish your data source, and then look at automating. Good luck

Comment: More specifically, if you want a server only solution, you can use Tableau Prep Conductor on the server to executed flows if you have purchased the Data Management add-on with your server (highly recommended). Alternatively, you can use the Tableau HyperAPI to convert your CSV to a hyper file and publish that data source

Comment: @AlexBlakemore Thank you! That is extremely helpful! I've started down the rabbit hole of converting the files to hyper using the hyper API, which I feel might give me the most control. But, I will also have to look into the prep conductor